# how to retrieve JSON data from URL in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert JSON data into objects of a C# class and display the values into a console program. My console window comes up blank each time I run it, I believe the problem is within CurrencyRates class but I am very new to this and unsure. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace Cooper_Lab12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var currencyRates = _download_serialized_json_data<CurrencyRates>("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4be3cf28d6954df2b87bf1bb7c2ba47b");

            Console.Read();
        }


        private static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new()
        {


            //var currencyRates = _download_serialized_json_data<CurrencyRates>(url);
            using (var w = new WebClient())
            {

                var json_data = string.Empty;
                // attempt to download JSON data as a string
                try
                {
                    json_data = w.DownloadString("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4be3cf28d6954df2b87bf1bb7c2ba47b ");
                }
                catch (Exception) { }
                // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
            }


        }
        public class RootObject
        {
            public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
            public string License { get; set; }
            public int Timestamp { get; set; }
            public string Base { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my CurrencyRates class:

```
public class CurrencyRates
{
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Currently it doesn't look as though you're writing to the console, which would be one reason it is blank. Could you try `Console.Write(currencyRates)` within your `Main` function?

Comment: If I add the into my Main, the console output is now:Cooper_Lab12.CurrencyRates

Comment: Okay, that is the expected value since your `_download_serialized_json_data` actually returns a _de-serialized_ object. You can loop over the `Rates` property and write to the console as the user Christos suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works. However, you don't try to output result to the console. That's why you don't see anything.

If you add the following to your `Main` method after the `currencyRates`, you will see the values that have been retrieved.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{currencyRates.Disclaimer}");
Console.WriteLine($"{currencyRates.License}");
Console.WriteLine($"{currencyRates.TimeStamp}");
Console.WriteLine($"{currencyRates.Base}");
foreach (var currencyRatesRate in currencyRates.Rates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {currencyRatesRate.Key}, Value: {currencyRatesRate.Value}");
}
```

*Notes*

Generally, it is better you follow standard naming conventions so that the readers of your code can quickly catch up on what is going on. For instance, all method names are written in [Pascal Case](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase). Use meaningful naming for your variables. For instance `webClient` is more meaningful than `w`. The variable names are written in [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). E.g `json_data` should be renamed in `jsonData`.

Avoid having many empty lines in your code. It would be far easier for the reader of your code to focus on a few lines and read your code.  Last but not least, you declare a parameter for your method of type string and you never use it. This parameter should be used instead of the hard-coded string in the `DownloadString` method.

Compare this refactored method with the one we had initially:

```
private static T DownloadAndDeserializeJsonData<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var jsonData = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            jsonData = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData) 
                   ? new T()
                   : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData);
    }
}
```

If you want a central place for naming guidelines for .NET Framework and C#, you could have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added your code but now I am getting am unhandled NullReferenceException on currencyRates.Rates

Comment: You are welcome. Actually I ran your code twice having added the `Console.WriteLine....` and I didn't notice that.

Comment: hmm, that is weird! the program keeps breaking a the NullReferenceExceptiom and I'm at a loss of  how to fix it

Comment: @ecooper10 It's seems a bit weird. Have you tried to debug it. Go to the line you call `DownloadString...` and press F9 a red mark should be appeared at the left. Then press F5. You program will start to run and very quickly it would stop at the line with the red mark. Then press F10 and hover with your mouse over the variable `json_data` (or `jsonData`, if you have refactored the method). What's the value? Furthermore, if you navigate to https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4be3cf28d6954df2b87bf1bb7c2ba47b from your browser don't you see the json you expect to be downloaded?

Comment: @ecooper10 Did you press F10? If yes then a yellow arrow would be appeared below the breakpoint. At this point if you hover over your variable you should see a string value there.

Comment: it just says "json_data" when I hover over the line and takes me back to my nullexception when I hit F10. I can however see that data in the link you sent above and it does display the data I would like to output into my console window

Comment: when using F10 the yellow arrow went up to line 23 from my breakpoint and highlights currencyRates.Rates. When I hovered the mouse over that it said it was "null"

Comment: Instead of using `catch(Excecption){ }` use `catch(Exception ex){ }` and follow exaclty the same steps as I mentioned before. By hitting F10 twice now, if any exception is thrown you would be able to hover over `ex` and see the message of the exception, which wouldbe more than helpful ! For instance if I delete the last three characters of the url and hover over the `ex` I see this message `{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}`, which apparently is the anticipated message, since I didn't pass an authorized `app_id`.

Comment: Okay in doing that It takes me to Exception ex and when I hover over ex it says null

Comment: @ecooper10 press once more F10 (If you stopped the debiggung, start it again and now press once more F10 when you get there again).

Comment: I hope you see now, why `catch(Exception){ }` is not a good practice. In a production environment you should have there a logging to a file or whatever, in order to record the exception and investigate later what went wrong.

Comment: I get "null" and "{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}...sorry hopefully I am following your instructions correctly. I really appreciate your help1

Comment: You haven't to ask sorry :) ! Ok, we now reached to something that would may help us to solve our problem. I will make a silly question, do you use *exactly* the following `DownloadString("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4be3cf28d6954df2b87bf1bb7c2ba47b ")`?

Comment: oh my goodness I found it, I have an extra space at the end of the url    >>>>>>>2ba47‌​b ") <<<<< fixed that and now its running perfectly! Thanks so much for your help, time, and patience!!!

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped. Believe or not I didn't reliazed the same issue. I am glad that now works. However, I don't get it, since I didn't realize the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Microsoft's Http libraries are not very developer friendly & therefore would like to propose an alternative & much easier way to do the above using the free & open-source [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) library.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ret API url
        string url = "https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=4be3cf28d6954df2b87bf1bb7c2ba47b";

        // GET Json data from api & map to CurrencyRates
        var todo =  url.GetJsonFromUrl().FromJson<CurrencyRates>();

        // print result to screen
        todo.PrintDump();
    }
    public class CurrencyRates
    {
        public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
        public string License { get; set; }
        public int TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public string Base { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

This is a much more concise / readable / maintainable way of getting the data from your external API.

You can achieve this by simply installing the Nuget package [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text); by running

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Text
```

in your NuGet Package console manager.

Comment: Maybe that was the case back then but now a days `await client.GetFromJsonAsync<>` works great without extra packages